# Find interpolated values in R

Tags: r, interpolation

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(0, 10, NA , 30, NA)
```

(not quite sure how to put NA values in the dataframe)

So.. my problem is, how to replace NA with interpolated values?

Comment: what are interpolated values?

Comment: `library(zoo); na.approx(y, rule = 2)`?

Comment: How exactly do you want to do interpolation? Do you want to do some sort of model fitting? A linear interpolation? You need to make some sort of assumption in order to fill in missing values. Be more clear on what the desired result is.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(0, 10, NA , 30, NA)

delta_y <- unique(na.omit(diff(y)))

for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  if (is.na(y[i])) {
    y[i] <- y[i - 1] + delta_y
  }
}

> y
[1]  0 10 20 30 40
```

I couldn't come up with a way to solve this without a loop, but I'm sure someone else will find a more efficient way.